# onListClickItem not responsing to anything

Tags: android, listview

When I click an item it doesnt run my onListItemClick code and I have no idea why!

I have a fragment extending listFragment with this code.  This is in the onCreateView()

```
{
adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, names);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) v;

    if (check.isChecked()){
        selections.remove((Integer) position);
    }
    else{
        selections.add((Integer) position);
    }

    //DOESNT RUN THIS

}
```

This is my custom adapter

```
package project.android.bellringing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;

public class CustomArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<Boolean> bitset = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private ArrayList<String> names;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId){
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}


public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> entries) {      
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);

    for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++){
        bitset.add(i, false);
    }

    names = new ArrayList<String>(entries);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     CheckedTextView c;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
         c = (CheckedTextView) vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);

    }
    else{
        c = (CheckedTextView) convertView;
    }

    final CheckedTextView ctv = c;
    ctv.setText(names.get(position));

    if (bitset.get(position) == false)
        ctv.setChecked(false);
    else
        ctv.setChecked(true);

    ctv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ctv.setChecked(!ctv.isChecked());

            if (bitset.get(position) == false)
                bitset.set(position, true);
            else
                bitset.set(position, false);
        }

    });


    return ctv;
}
```

}

Comment: Was my sample helpful or do you need some other information?

Answer (score 0):

Got something, Your `CheckedTextView` is stealing the input touch, so define it as `Not focusable` in your `xml`

Comment: You can see it all there. So no

Answer (score 0):

Problem is focusability of `CheckedTextView` in `ListView`. You can fix it setting  `android:focusable="false"` in your layout for CheckedTextView.

This causes that `OnItemClick` will be called but `OnClickListener` on your `CheckedTextView` is not called and you have to handle checked and unchecked state yourself. I was interested in it so i made a sample. Explanation of it would be probably longer and more complicated than the code so here it is:

Core part is handling `CheckedTextView` state in `onItemClick` and also handling the state at the end of `getView` and the state is held in `BooleanSparseArray` which is updated from `onItemClick`.

```
public class TestListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private TestAdapter mTestAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);
        final List<String> names = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"});

        mTestAdapter = new TestAdapter(this, names);

        setListAdapter(mTestAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) v;

        boolean toggleChecked = !checkedTextView.isChecked(); //toggle checked state
        checkedTextView.setChecked(toggleChecked);
        checkedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(toggleChecked ? android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background : 0); //setting correct check mark

        //setting the flag to properly refresh when scrolling
        mTestAdapter.setChecked(position, toggleChecked);
    }

    private static class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        private SparseBooleanArray bitset = new SparseBooleanArray();

        private TestAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects)
        {
            super(context, 0, objects);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean checked)
        {
            bitset.append(position, checked);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                checkedTextView= (CheckedTextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checked, null);
            }
            else
            {
                checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView;
            }

            boolean isChecked = bitset.get(position);
            checkedTextView.setChecked(isChecked); //setting checked to correct state
            checkedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(isChecked ? android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background : 0); // setting correct check mark
            checkedTextView.setText(getItem(position));

            return checkedTextView;
        }
    }
}
```